# Converting form data to JSON using JSON.stringify($("#login").serializeArray() yields strange results

Tags: jquery, json, rest, jakarta-ee

I want to capture the form data and convert to `JSON` before it is submitted as a `REST` `POST` request. I am able to convert it `JSON`, but not in the way I want.
The `HTML` file:

```
<form name="login" id="login" action="http://localhost:9091/peerby/user/" method="post">
        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
        <input id="fname" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" type="text"/>
        <br>
        <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
        <input id="lname" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" type="text"/>
        <br>
        <label for="adr">Address</label>
        <input id="adr" name="address" placeholder="Address" type="text"/>
        <br>
        <label for="eml">Email</label>
        <input id="eml" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email"/>
        <br>
        <label for="pswd">Password</label>
        <input id="pswd" name="password" placeholder="password" type="password"/>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" id="log"/>
    </form>
<script>
        $('#login').submit(function() {
            var formData = JSON.stringify($("#login").serializeArray());
            console.log(formData);
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
            xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:9091/peerby/user/", true); 
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            xhr.send(formData);
            return false;
    });
    </script>
```

The log output I get is:

```
[{"name":"firstName","value":"a"},{"name":"lastName","value":"a"},{"name":"address","value":"a"},{"name":"email","value":"a@a"},{"name":"password","value":"a"}]
```

The **output I want** is:

```
{
    "firstName": "goodbye",
    "lastName": "world",
    "address": "asgard",
    "email": "asgard@galaxy.com",
    "password": "dark"
}
```

and the error I get is:

```
Exception Description: Cannot add the object [org.vamsi.prototype.usermodel.UserModel@28768a27], of class [class org.vamsi.prototype.usermodel.UserModel], to container [class org.vamsi.prototype.usermodel.UserModel].
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.vamsi.prototype.usermodel.UserModel cannot be cast to java.util.Collection
```

The error is because the `UserModel` class does not take `Collection` as an argument.

I tried using `var formData = JSON.stringify($("#login")` without `.serializeArray()`, I get:

```
{"0":{"0":{},"1":{},"2":{},"3":{},"4":{},"5":{},"jQuery321028725349478778071":{"events":{"submit":[{"type":"submit","origType":"submit","data":null,"guid":1,"namespace":""}]}}},"length":1}
```

I am able to `POST`, but this is not the result I want.

How can I convert the `form` to `JSON` and `POST`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use the following to `reduce()` the array to object you want

```js
let formData = $('form').serializeArray().reduce((obj, field) => {
  obj[field.name] = field.value;
  return obj;
}, {});

// demo display
$('pre').text(JSON.stringify(formData, null, ' '))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>
  Processed Data
</h3>
<pre></pre>
<form name="login" id="login" action="http://localhost:9091/peerby/user/" method="post">
  <label for="fname">First Name</label>
  <input id="fname" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" type="text" value="foo" />
  <br>
  <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
  <input id="lname" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" value="bar" />
  <br>
  <label for="adr">Address</label>
  <input id="adr" name="address" placeholder="Address" type="text" value="123 some st" />
  <br>
  <label for="eml">Email</label>
  <input id="eml" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" value="foo@bar.com" />
  <br>
  <label for="pswd">Password</label>
  <input id="pswd" name="password" placeholder="password" type="password" value="abcde" />
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Login" id="log" />
</form>
```

Comment: It works in the `pre` tag, but when I try to `submit` the form data with and without removing the `value` attribute in the form, I get `HTTP Status 415 – Unsupported Media Type` and when I check chrome console I see `POST http://localhost:9091/peerby/user/ 415 ()` and `Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'shortcut' of undefined
    at chrome-extension://faminaibgiklngmfpfbhmokfmnglamcm/js/script.js:3:9`